# Buffering multiple features according to an attribute field?

Tags: python, buffer

I'm trying to build a buffer tool with Python that will function according to the attribute field that contains varying widths. I am building a inventory of streets and need to add a buffer to the line feature that would represent an accurate width of each street. I have recorded all the widths in the attribute field and want to use this field to determine the buffer. Is there a way I can do them all in bulk with Python?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. Are you planning to use a specific library (*e.g.* `arcpy`) or are you open to accomplish this using any Python library?

Comment: Anything that would work. I am new to building tools in Python but very familiar with Arcmap in general.

Comment: So you probably want an ArcGIS based solution (*i.e* `arcpy`). Can you edit your question to give some clairty? When you say tool are you refering to an ArcGIS tool you can share or a simple script that creates the buffers?

Comment: Absolutely no python required, just use the buffer tool in ArcMap, you can choose a field as the width, strongly suggest you read the help file before you do anything as anything else is wasting your time!

Comment: I am looking for a script that will create a buffer around a line feature that is 1/2 the width recorded in the attribute field.